# Rails 4.0 with Devise. Nested attributes Unpermited parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I am working on a web-app using Devise and Rails 4. I have a **User** model which I have extended with 2 extra form fields such that when a user signs up he can also submit his first/last names. (based on http://blog.12spokes.com/web-design-development/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4/). I now want to add a **Institution** model. This model **has_many** :users, and a user **belongs_to** :institution. I want to be able to register the **institution's name** on the same form I register the user. I know I need a nested_attribute in my **Institution** model, since this is the parent, which I will show in a bit. When I try to sign up the user I get in the console: **Unpermited parameters: Institutions**.

My hint is that I cannot update my parent class(Institution) based upon my child class (User). Might there be a solution to this? Or has anyone experienced something similar?

```
class Institutions < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
     belongs_to :institution
end
```

**registrations/new.html.erb** Here I have the nested form

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|     %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
.
. 
    <%= f.fields_for :institutions do |i| %>
        <p><%= i.label :name %><br />
        <%= i.text_field :institutions_attr %></p>
    <% end %>
```

Based on the tutorial I have linked earlier, I have created a new **User::ParameterSanitizer** which inherits from the **Devise::ParameterSanitizer** and overridden the **`sign_up`** method as follows:

**lib/user_sanitizer.rb**

```
private
def sign_up
    default_params.permit(:first_name, :last_name ,:email, :password,  :password_confirmation, :current_password, institutions_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

Finally, my **application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected
  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == User
    User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
    else 
    super
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you for reading!

**Console params output:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"JKuN6K5l0iwFsj/25B7GKDj7WEHR4DO3oaVyGxGJKvU=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"abc@foo.com",
 "first_name"=>"abc",
 "last_name"=>"xyz",
 "institutions"=>{"name"=>"Government"},
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

**EDIT**

As suggested, I have added

```
params.require(resource_name).permit( :email, :first_name, :last_name, institution:  [:name], :password, :password_confirmation ) and I get an *error syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...nstitution: [:name], :password, :password_confirmation )*
```

BUT, if I re-edit to

```
params.require(resource_name).permit( :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, institution:  [:name] )
```

I get NO syntax error but I get Unpermited parameters: Institutions in the Request.

My belief is that this happens because User is a child of Institution. I have, however, been unable to find a work-around this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**config/routes.rb**

Create your own registration controller like so ... ([see Devise documentation for the details of overriding controllers here ...](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)) ... which is  more elegant way as opposed to doing it via the `ApplicationController`

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations'}
```

**app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**

Override the new method to create a `Profile` associated with the `User` model as below ... run the `configure_permitted_parameters` method before to sanitize the parameters (*note how to add nested parameters*)

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  # GET /users/sign_up
  def new

    # Override Devise default behaviour and create a profile as well
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_profile
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes => :fullname)
    }
  end
end
```

**db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_create_profiles.rb**

This is the migration that generates the `Profile` model (*note the reference to `User`*) ... this example profile only keeps `fullname` as an extension of the `User` but feel free to add as you wish!

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
       t.references :user
       t.string :fullname
       t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

  # Allow saving of attributes on associated records through the parent,
  # :autosave option is automatically enabled on every association
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  # Devise
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**app/models/profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  belongs_to :user

  # Validations
  validates :fullname, presence: true
end
```

**app/views/devise/registrations/new.html**

```
<% resource.build_profile if resource.profile.nil? %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name,
                       :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <ul>

    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <li class="fullname">
      <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_fields| %>
        <%= profile_fields.label :fullname %>
        <%= profile_fields.text_field :fullname %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
    <li class="email">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %>
    </li>
    <li class="password">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </li>
    <li class="password">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p><%= render "devise/shared/links" %></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks much King'ori, this is exactly what I was looking for! Saved me a few extra hours of frustration.

Comment: @king'ori Maina I am using devise_auth_token gem and after falling above methods for the same gem I am still getting Unpermitted parameter: account error in my server log

Comment: @Anjan Unfortunately I haven't used `devise_auth_token` before so don't know where to start. I'd guess that the `Unpermitted parameter: account` error means that the `:account` parameter needs to be added to the allowed parameters. See `configure_permitted_parameters` method in the `Users::RegistrationsController` class above on how I added profile attributes.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the correct answer!

Answer (score 12):

You must create your own registration controller to do so, here is how:

***routes.rb***

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

***Controller***

You must replace `:your_fields` by the fields you want to allow (sorry if I leave that to you, but that makes my answer more general, therefore usable for anyone that would pass by)

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

    def sign_up_params
      allow = [:email, :your_fields, :password, :password_confirmation]
      params.require(resource_name).permit(allow)
    end

end
```

**Additional info (nested attributes + some testing)**

Also note that if you are using association and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you will have `params` structured like this

`model: {field, field, field, associated_model: {field, field}}`

And off course you must use the same structure in your `sign_up_params` method. If you need to understand this, you can change the content of `sign_up_params` method like this:

```
    def sign_up_params
      params.require(resource_name).permit!
    end
```

That will allow any param, then post your form (it should pass this time) and look into your rails console to see the structure of `params`, finally you can set-up `sign_up_params` method correctly

Check this for more info http://www.railsexperiments.com/using-strong-parameters-with-nested-forms/

In your case you should use:

`params.require(resource_name).permit( :email, :first_name, :last_name, institutions: [:name], :password, :password_confirmation )`

Comment: Thx for the reply. I did try this. I does not work since it still does not permit the parameters of the Institution model.

Comment: I saw that ^_^. I did write it the following way: allow = [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :name], where :name is a field in the other model.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the fact that User is a child of Institution. Or maybe I am wrong

Comment: By the way, the part `params.require(resource_name)` rely on the fact that User is the 'parent' model, but in your case you should replace `resource_name` by `:institution`. On the other hand I don't know how devise will react to that, but that's another question (we are talking here about strong params, right?)

Comment: Yes we are talking about strong params, and yes the User is the child in this instance. I have replaced resource_name and got this "param not found: institution", so I'm guessing it's not working.

Comment: "param not found: institution" means params does not contain :institution, or it is empty. I assume you did not follow my advise on testing with `.permit!`. You must find this part of your answer by yourself now (I can't test it for you)

Comment: I did exactly this: params.require(:institution).permit! and the error comes from ActionController::ParameterMissing in RegistrationsController#create. And in the request I get this "institutions"=>{"name"=>"xyz"}

Comment: Paste your whole params line found in the console please (edit your question, it's more readeable)

Comment: Ok edited my answer, I hope that's it cause I gotta go now :) good luck

Comment: No problem. You can give me rep by accepting the answer, this is how stackoverflow works :) cheers

Comment: I'm still using the same technique in all my projects while keep them to the last rails version. It works I confirm

Answer (score 7):

Using rails 5.1 and devise 4.4.1 following is the shortest and works pretty good:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
after_initialize do
  build_profile if new_record? && profile.blank?
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [{ profile_attributes: :name }])
end
```

The key here is that you can do following without making separate controller:

- permit nested attributes
- build relation for form builder