# Rails 5 with Devise - Devise User has_one Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms, accepts-nested-attributes

I am making a website  for an existing database. This database is from a game and I can't make many changes in the existing tables.

I decided to use Devise as the authentication solution.
I will use the User model from Devise for the website and the database has a Login table with some important informations.

They will have a **one to one association** where the User has_one Login and the Login belongs to User.

I changed the User registration form to have some Login information. I used nested form for that. When I signup it should create the User and Login.

I'm trying this create part but it's not working. I tried many different ways but it never works. The two main problems are:

1. it creates the User but do not create the Login
2. it creates both but the Login does not have the information that i
   put in the form. They are all blank

I tried many different ways:

- override the new method in the RegistrationController using resource.build_login
- override sign_up_params method with permit inside
- put the resource.build_login in the new view
- override build_resource and put resource.build_login there

None of them works.

I'm using Rails 5.0.2 and Devise 4.2.0.

These are the models:

```
class Login < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :login
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :login
end
```

One important question is where should I put the **accepts_nested_attributes_for**? I saw people using it in the Model that has belong and I also saw people using in the has_one model.

This is my RegistrationController:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
    resource.build_login
  end
  def create
    super
  end
  def sign_up_params
    params.require(resource_name).permit(:email, :password, 
                   :password_confirmation, login_attributes:  
                   [:userid, :birthdate, :sex])
  end
end
```

And this is my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: 
                    registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, class: 'form-
              control' %>
  <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("No mínimo #
              {@minimum_password_length} caracteres" if 
               @minimum_password_length) %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :login do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input :userid %>
    <%= ff.input :birthdate %>
    <%= ff.label :sex %>
    <%= ff.input_field :sex, collection: [['Feminino', 'F'], 
               ['Masculino', 'M']], class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Cadastrar', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

I hope that all the information needed are there.

Most answers I found for this problem were to Rails 4 or Rails 3 and maybe they didn't work for me because I'm using Rails 5.

**Edit #1:** Added create method in RegistrationController.

**Edit #2:** With `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in user the fields doesn't appear so I changed `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to login model.

And here is the log for how the code is now:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-14 20:24:40 -0300
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>
      "habj5iep5SaE5nkyimzFyVslsCAIvy7ZokmM
       KA8WDgbgQkYCa/mofo83sllRiwX13OCkPXIjbkR+CcDKBICXOw==",
       "user"=>{"email"=>"breno@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
       "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>
      {"userid"=>"breno1", "birthdate"=>"13/07/2017", "sex"=>"M"}}, 
       "commit"=>"Cadastrar"}
Unpermitted parameter: login
(10.8ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (10.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE 
  `users`.`email` = BINARY 'breno@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
SQL (11.5ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `encrypted_password`, 
  `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('breno@gmail.com', 
  '$2a$11$4le6ZB5JyrYZGYLXvtlwa.c6BA463BvNYkSINfU0C10LoJADEYJ8q', 
  '2017-07-14 23:24:41', '2017-07-14 23:24:41')
(18.3ms)  COMMIT
(12.6ms)  BEGIN
SQL (11.0ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `sign_in_count` = 1, 
  `current_sign_in_at` = '2017-07-14 23:24:41', `last_sign_in_at` = 
  '2017-07-14 23:24:41', `current_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1', 
  `last_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1' WHERE `users`.`id` = 33
(11.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 436ms (ActiveRecord: 85.8ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-14 20:24:41 -0300
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
User Load (13.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` 
  = 33 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Login Load (11.1ms)  SELECT  `login`.* FROM `login` WHERE 
  `login`.`user_id` = 33 LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_side_navbar.html.erb (26.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 619ms (ActiveRecord: 24.8ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `userid' for 
  nil:NilClass):
4:       <div class="sidenav-header-inner text-center">
5:         <%= image_tag 'avatar-1.jpg', class: 'img-fluid rounded-
    circle' %>
6:         <h2 class="h5 text-uppercase">
7:           <%= current_user.login.userid %>
8:         </h2>
9:         <span class="text-uppercase">
10:           <%= current_user.is_admin? ? 'administrador' : 'jogador' 
    %>

app/views/layouts/_side_navbar.html.erb:7:in 
`_app_views_layouts__side_navbar_html_erb__415501206315934300_
    70011534596860'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:13:in 
`_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1458307398416558594_
    70011827322320'
Rendering /home/prikster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-
    5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
    template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
Rendering /home/prikster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-
    5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
    _source.html.erb
Rendered /home/prikster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-
    5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
    _source.html.erb (32.9ms)
Rendering /home/prikster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-
    5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
    _trace.html.erb
Rendered /home/prikster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-
    5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
    _trace.html.erb (5.0ms)
Rendering /home/prikster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-
    5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
    _request_and_response.html.erb
Rendered /home/prikster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-
    5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
    _request_and_response.html.erb (1.7ms)
Rendered /home/prikster/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-
    5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
    template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (62.6ms)
```

Is `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the right model?

In the log there is a line pointing to an `Unpermitted parameter: login`. What should I do to correct this?

Comment: Can you post the logs that appear as soon as you click submit?

Comment: Also can you show us the create method?

Comment: I added the create method. As you can see it's just calling super for devise's create method.
As for the log, I am at work now and as soon as I get home I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I just had to add a `required: false` to Login's relation with User.

My Login model is like this now:

```
class Login < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, required: false
end
```

I think the problem was when it tried to create/save Login the User didn't had the id yet.

In the end both models are created, with relation between them and they both have their attributes with their right values.

Comment: Yes. this is why I would recommend you to read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767449/rails-4-0-with-devise-nested-attributes-unpermited-parameters and Devise Wiki: