# Devise sign up with nested attributes make attributes required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a two model setup, users and profiles. I am using devise 4.2 for authentication and am filling out the profile via nested attributes, as done here [Rails 4.0 with Devise. Nested attributes Unpermited parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767449/rails-4-0-with-devise-nested-attributes-unpermited-parameters)

I would like to make it so that devise will not submit the form without the nested attributes filled out by the user. (making them required attributes) How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make changes in devise registrations views. 
Generate views for both models: `rails g devise:views users` and `rails g devise:views profiles`.

Open `registrations/new.html.erb` and add html5 `required:true` attribute to required fields, ex. for email `<%= f.email_field :email, required: true %>`

When open your a nested model and be sure validation is existed for necessary fields, ex.: `validates :first_name, presence: true`.

Comment: The second half of your answer is very helpful, ideally though, I would like to be able to have devise handle the errors, not html5.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Have you added validations to a nested model? The answer is updated.