# Vue to Rails: how can I post to create a nested object through strong params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

Given a Rails backend and a Vue frontend, how can I POST to the nested `ImageAttachment` class? A `Photo` can have one `ImageAttachment`. I have these strong parameters set up, it feels like the issue is there but I can't find anything.

```
def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(
    image_attachment: %i[data crop_x crop_y crop_width crop_height revert]
  )
end
```

This is the Vue function that attaches the child (`ImageAttachment`) info to the parent `Photo`.

```
uploading: function (file, xhr, formData) {
  formData.append('photo[image_attachment][data]', file)
}
```

But how it stands gives this error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - ImageAttachment(#70277552586900) expected, got {"data"=>#, @original_filename="30594959_1160903097380019_7860735199103942656_o.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image_attachment][data]\"; filename=\"30594959_1160903097380019_7860735199103942656_o.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70277506611620):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way around this is to *leverage* the `_attributes`. JS:

```
uploading: function (file, xhr, formData) {
  formData.append('photo[image_attachment_attributes][data]', file)
}
```

Model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_attachment, allow_destroy: true
```

Controller:

```
def create
  if @photo.update_attributes!(photo_params)
    response = @photo.reload && @photo.exists? ? @photo.for_vue : nil
    render json: { photo: response }, status: 200
  else
    render json: { error: @photo.errors }, status: 400
  end
end

private

def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(
    image_attachment_attributes:
      %i[data crop_x crop_y crop_width crop_height revert]
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had `AssociationTypeMismatch`. I was using `accept_nested_attributes in model`. In your example `image_attachment` stands for association probably, thats why the error. 
I would use `attr_accessor : imgattachment` and in controller something like this

```
photo = Photo.new
img_attachment = ImageAttachment.new
img_attachment.data = params[:imgattachment][:data]
photo.image_attachment << img_attachment
```

My topic: [ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch when trying to register user using devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862218/activerecordassociationtypemismatch-when-trying-to-register-user-using-devise)

Seems its problem with `accept_nested_attributes`